# Two screens on 4k and 150%

Tags: dell, screen, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I have two screens with 4k resolution:

- Dell XPS 15 9570 (Vidia® GeForce GTX1050Ti MaxQ + Intel HD Graphics 630)
- Benq PD2700U

On the Benq only half of the screen is visible.

[image: Photo of monitors]

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please explain your question a little more? Without a detailed description of the problem you are having, we may have trouble helping you.

Comment: @Marek Trzynski Please advise the make and model of your PC and each monitor, and which video card is used for each monitor. Also, what happens if you exchange the video cables at the back of the PC; does the problem move? Please answer by clicking on [edit] and adding the information to your original question; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Please check once again, i provide more details.